# Avoid duplicated record in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
// Check to see if p_name exists
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT patient_name FROM patient WHERE patient_name = '" . $p_name . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
       // patient database
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO patient (patient_name)
                   VALUES ( '$p_name' )") or die (mysql_error());
       }
    else
       die ("Patient name exist!");
```

Why does it still insert new record even if the patient_name exist in the database?

Is `if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)` correct?

Comment: use `UNIQUE`...and use `mysqli` as `mysql_()` are going to be deprecated soon

Comment: Are you sure that there's not an error in the query?  You don't check `mysql_error`

Comment: use TRIM and check the case

Comment: did you try the query in mysql ?

Comment: he's lucky everyone in the world has a `UNIQUE` name :D

Comment: @user2023235 of course lol

Comment: @ExplosionPills Not that I know of. I just don't want it has a duplicated item in the database.

Comment: @user2023235 you dont even know where he is using this, how about if he use it in a closed network with few people?

Comment: No. There are no errors during execution.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ahh, maybe I should start using the new one now. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @amnbhrm wise decision

Answer (score 1):

The query probably failed for some reason. That means `$sql` is a boolean FALSE. You try to pass that `FALSE` to `mysql_num_rows()`, which also fails, since it expects to get a result handle. That means mysql_num_rows() also returns a boolean `FALSE`. In PHP, `false == 0` is `TRUE`, so you execute your insert statement.

**NEVER** assume a query has succeeded. **ALWAYS** check for failure. That means, as a bare minimum, you have:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Initially the condition was like this, `mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0`. It simply says that there are already the same record in the db. That's why I put **==** there. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, that'd work. it's racy, though... nothing says some OTHER script can't be doing the exact same thing and happen to get its insert through before this particular run.